# Predictions computed by ggpredict() and ggemmeans() for a mixed-effect model differ: why?

Tags: r, predict, emmeans, glmmtmb, ggeffects

I used functions `ggpredict()` and `ggemmeans()` from package `ggeffects` 1.3.0 to calculate mean estimates and confidence intervals (hereafter: CI) for a mixed-effect model. These functions rely on `predict()` and on `emmeans()` and make their outputs ggplot-friendly. The values predicted/estimated by the two functions differ both in their mean values and in their CI. Why?

The following reproducible example is based on dataset RIKZ (Janssen e Mulder 2005; Zuur et al. 2007), which looks at how species richness (number of species) varies with the height of sampling stations compared to mean tidal level (NAP, in meters) and the level of exposure (factor with three levels: low, medium and high):

```
rm(list=ls())
if (!require(pacman)) install.packages('pacman'); library(pacman)
p_load(emmeans)
p_load(ggplot2)
p_load(ggpubr)
p_load(ggeffects)
p_load(lme4, lmerTest, glmmTMB)
p_load(RCurl)
# get data:
RIKZ <- read.csv(text = RCurl::getURL(
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/marcoplebani85/datasets/master/RIKZ.csv"))
str(RIKZ)
# "Exposure" is a factor:
RIKZ$Exposure <- as.factor(RIKZ$Exposure)
```

Here I fit a generalised mixed-effect model with Poisson-distributed residuals to the data using `glmmTMB()`:

```
mem1 <- glmmTMB(Richness ~ NAP+Exposure + (1 | Beach),
                family="poisson",
                data = RIKZ, REML=T)
```

Model predictions and CI according to `ggeffects::ggpredict()`, *without* accounting for the uncertainty of random effects (see [this page](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/introduction_randomeffects.html) on why accounting for it or not):

```
richness.predicted <- ggpredict(mem1, 
terms=c("NAP", "Exposure"), type="fixed")
```

Predictions and CI **for the same model** according to `ggeffects::ggemmeans()`, *without* accounting for the uncertainty of random effects:

```
richness.emmeans <- ggemmeans(mem1, 
terms=c("NAP", "Exposure"), type="fixed")
```

Graphs representing the two sets of model predictions and CI together with the observed data:

```
p1 <- plot(richness.predicted, add.data=T) + 
    labs(title="Predictions by ggpredict()") + ylim(0,45) +
    theme(text = element_text(size = 15))
p2 <- plot(richness.emmeans, add.data=T) + 
    labs(title="Predictions by ggemmeans()") + ylim(0,45) +
    theme(text = element_text(size = 15))
ggarrange(p1, p2, ncol=2, labels=c("(a)", "(b)"), 
    common.legend=T, legend="bottom")
```

[image]

**Why do the two sets of mean estimates and confidence intervals differ?**

*UPDATE*:

[This page](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/technical_differencepredictemmeans.html) explains the differences between the two functions:

> [...] effects returned by `ggpredict()` [are] conditional effects (i.e. these
> are conditioned on certain (reference) levels of factors), while
> `ggemmeans()` returns marginal means, since the effects are
> “marginalized” (or “averaged”) over the levels of factors. However,
> these differences only apply to non-focal terms, i.e. remaining
> variables that are not specified in the terms argument.

It continues:

> When all categorical predictors are specified in terms and further
> (non-focal) terms are only numeric, results are also identical (as
> both `ggpredict()` and `ggemmeans()` use the mean value by default to hold
> non-focal numeric variables constant).

I suspect the reason for the differences in the predictions obtained by the two functions for mixed-effect models lies in how they handle random effects, but I don't know how.

---

*REFERENCES*:

1. Janssen, G. and Mulder, S. (2005), *Zonation of macrofauna across sandy beaches and surf zones along the Dutch coast.* Oceanologia 47(2): 265-282.
2. Zuur, A.F., Ieno, E.N., and Smith, G.M. (2007), *Analysing ecological data.* Springer Science & Business Media
3. https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/introduction_randomeffects.html
4. https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/technical_differencepredictemmeans.html

Comment: Why aren’t you using ggemmeans instead of ggpredict.

Comment: @IRTFM the difference in prediction confidence of ggpredict() and emmeans is what I am curious about. Function ggemmeans() is simply a ggplot-friendly version of emmeans(), which is what I used here.

Comment: You’re asking for prediction on a mixed model first. Are you askin for a mixed model in the second run?

Comment: I think that `ggpredict` is probably using `se.fit=TRUE` from `glmmTMB:::predict.glmmTMB`, which incorporates the joint uncertainty of all model parameters (fixed-effect `beta` and covariance `theta`, as well as random parameters `b`), while `emmeans` might be using only the uncertainty in the fixed effect parameters. This is a good question, I will take another look when I get a chance.

Comment: @IRTFM they are two different sets of predictions for the very same model.

Comment: Ben will probably be your ticket to enlightenment.

Comment: @BenBolker Hello, thanks for your feedback. I have since updated my question. Both `ggemmeans()` and `ggpredict()` have an argument `type=` which allows to account for the uncertainty of random effects or not. The default option is `type="fixed"` (now explicit in my example), so both functions *should* be drawing estimates and CI based only on the uncertainty in the fixed effect parameters. Besides, if `ggemmeans()` were using only the uncertainty in the fixed effect parameters, wouldn't it result in narrower CIs than they would be if it were also accounting for random effect uncertainty?

Comment: For what is worth, `ggpredict` and `ggemmeans` give the same answer if you set `REML = FALSE`. They also give the same answer if you fit the model with `lme4::glmer` which uses ML and doesn't have the REML option. So the difference is due to the estimation method.

Comment: @dipetkov thanks! That's the closest we have to an answer so far. You should publish that as an answer and cash the bounty before it expires :-)

Comment: This was a helpful discussion - I added a short section to the vignette (https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/introduction_randomeffects.html) explaining the different results depending on whether REML or ML was used during model fitting.

Answer (score 3):

For `type = "fixed"`, `predict(..., re.form = NA)` is used. While for `type = "random"`, `predict(..., re.form = NULL)` is used. To get same results, try:

```r
ggpredict(mem1,
  terms = c("NAP", "Exposure"), type = "random", interval = "confidence"
)
```

See different outputs here:

```r
rm(list = ls())
if (!require(pacman)) install.packages("pacman")
#> Loading required package: pacman
library(pacman)
p_load(emmeans)
p_load(ggplot2)
p_load(ggpubr)
p_load(ggeffects)
p_load(lme4, lmerTest, glmmTMB)
p_load(RCurl)
# get data:
RIKZ <- read.csv(text = RCurl::getURL(
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/marcoplebani85/datasets/master/RIKZ.csv"
))
# "Exposure" is a factor:
RIKZ$Exposure <- as.factor(RIKZ$Exposure)

mem1 <- glmmTMB(Richness ~ NAP + Exposure + (1 | Beach),
  family = "poisson",
  data = RIKZ, REML = T
)

d <- new_data(mem1, c("NAP [-1, 0, 1]", "Exposure"))
predict(mem1, newdata = d, type = "response", re.form = NULL)
#> [1]  5.442088  3.293444  1.993127 20.725116 12.542431  7.590432 11.230864
#> [8]  6.796697  4.113227
predict(mem1, newdata = d, type = "response", re.form = NA)
#> [1]  5.526114  3.306028  1.977849 20.919609 12.515270  7.487329 11.598996
#> [8]  6.939163  4.151392
emmeans::emmeans(mem1, c("NAP", "Exposure"), at = list(NAP = c(-1, 0, 1)), type = "response")
#>  NAP Exposure  rate    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
#>   -1 high      5.44 0.984 Inf      3.82      7.76
#>    0 high      3.29 0.543 Inf      2.38      4.55
#>    1 high      1.99 0.359 Inf      1.40      2.84
#>   -1 low      20.73 5.126 Inf     12.76     33.65
#>    0 low      12.54 3.015 Inf      7.83     20.09
#>    1 low       7.59 1.936 Inf      4.60     12.51
#>   -1 medium   11.23 1.695 Inf      8.35     15.10
#>    0 medium    6.80 0.923 Inf      5.21      8.87
#>    1 medium    4.11 0.647 Inf      3.02      5.60
#> 
#> Confidence level used: 0.95 
#> Intervals are back-transformed from the log scale


# fixed effects with confidence intervals, conditioned on random effects
# i.e. using `re.form = NULL`
ggpredict(mem1,
  terms = c("NAP [-1, 0, 1]", "Exposure"), type = "random", interval = "confidence"
)
#> # Predicted counts of Richness
#> 
#> # Exposure = high
#> 
#> NAP | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>  -1 |      5.44 | [3.82, 7.76]
#>   0 |      3.29 | [2.38, 4.55]
#>   1 |      1.99 | [1.40, 2.84]
#> 
#> # Exposure = low
#> 
#> NAP | Predicted |         95% CI
#> --------------------------------
#>  -1 |     20.73 | [12.76, 33.65]
#>   0 |     12.54 | [ 7.83, 20.09]
#>   1 |      7.59 | [ 4.60, 12.51]
#> 
#> # Exposure = medium
#> 
#> NAP | Predicted |        95% CI
#> -------------------------------
#>  -1 |     11.23 | [8.35, 15.10]
#>   0 |      6.80 | [5.21,  8.87]
#>   1 |      4.11 | [3.02,  5.60]
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * Beach = NA (population-level)

ggemmeans(mem1,
  terms = c("NAP [-1, 0, 1]", "Exposure"), type = "fixed"
)
#> # Predicted counts of Richness
#> 
#> # Exposure = high
#> 
#> NAP | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>  -1 |      5.44 | [3.82, 7.76]
#>   0 |      3.29 | [2.38, 4.55]
#>   1 |      1.99 | [1.40, 2.84]
#> 
#> # Exposure = low
#> 
#> NAP | Predicted |         95% CI
#> --------------------------------
#>  -1 |     20.73 | [12.76, 33.65]
#>   0 |     12.54 | [ 7.83, 20.09]
#>   1 |      7.59 | [ 4.60, 12.51]
#> 
#> # Exposure = medium
#> 
#> NAP | Predicted |        95% CI
#> -------------------------------
#>  -1 |     11.23 | [8.35, 15.10]
#>   0 |      6.80 | [5.21,  8.87]
#>   1 |      4.11 | [3.02,  5.60]

# fixed effects with prediction intervals, conditioned on random effects
# i.e. reform = NULL
ggpredict(mem1,
  terms = c("NAP [-1, 0, 1]", "Exposure"), type = "random"
)
#> # Predicted counts of Richness
#> 
#> # Exposure = high
#> 
#> NAP | Predicted |        95% CI
#> -------------------------------
#>  -1 |      5.44 | [0.74, 39.88]
#>   0 |      3.29 | [0.45, 24.01]
#>   1 |      1.99 | [0.27, 14.60]
#> 
#> # Exposure = low
#> 
#> NAP | Predicted |         95% CI
#> --------------------------------
#>  -1 |     20.73 | [2.75, 156.08]
#>   0 |     12.54 | [1.67,  94.15]
#>   1 |      7.59 | [1.00,  57.38]
#> 
#> # Exposure = medium
#> 
#> NAP | Predicted |        95% CI
#> -------------------------------
#>  -1 |     11.23 | [1.55, 81.52]
#>   0 |      6.80 | [0.94, 49.13]
#>   1 |      4.11 | [0.57, 29.91]
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * Beach = NA (population-level)
#> 
#> Intervals are prediction intervals. Use `interval = "confidence"` to
#>   return regular confidence intervals.

# fixed effects with confidence intervals, using `re.form = NA`
ggpredict(mem1,
  terms = c("NAP [-1, 0, 1]", "Exposure"), type = "fixed"
)
#> # Predicted counts of Richness
#> 
#> # Exposure = high
#> 
#> NAP | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>  -1 |      5.53 | [4.15, 7.36]
#>   0 |      3.31 | [2.57, 4.26]
#>   1 |      1.98 | [1.48, 2.64]
#> 
#> # Exposure = low
#> 
#> NAP | Predicted |         95% CI
#> --------------------------------
#>  -1 |     20.92 | [15.91, 27.51]
#>   0 |     12.52 | [ 9.72, 16.11]
#>   1 |      7.49 | [ 5.55, 10.09]
#> 
#> # Exposure = medium
#> 
#> NAP | Predicted |        95% CI
#> -------------------------------
#>  -1 |     11.60 | [9.47, 14.21]
#>   0 |      6.94 | [5.85,  8.23]
#>   1 |      4.15 | [3.29,  5.23]
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * Beach = NA (population-level)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I have added some more details to the docs and vignettes, to clarify the differences. Website will be updated soon.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for taking the time to write an answer (and to create `ggeffects`!). I'll have to figure out the difference between `re.form = NA` and `re.form = NULL`. I'll look into the updated docs/vignettes ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

This really a comment, not a full answer, but perhaps it could point into the right direction to understand this subtle difference between `ggpredict` and `ggemmeans` which is actually a difference between [`predict.glmmTMB`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/glmmTMB/versions/1.1.7/topics/predict.glmmTMB) and [`emmeans`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/emmeans/versions/1.8.8/topics/emmeans).

[`glmmTMB`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/index.html) uses two estimation methods: ML (maximum likelihood) and REML (restricted maximum likelihood). One chooses one or the other method by setting the argument `REML` appropriately.

If the estimation method is ML, then `ggpredict` and `ggemeans` give the same result. The difference occurs when the estimation method is REML and the model has random effects.

```r
fit_glmmTMB <- glmmTMB(
  Richness ~ NAP + Exposure + (1 | Beach),
  family = poisson,
  data = RIKZ,
  REML = FALSE # Use ML to fit the model.
)

ggpredict(
  fit_glmmTMB, terms = fixed_terms, type = "fixed"
)
#> # Predicted counts of Richness
#> 
#> # Exposure = medium
#> 
#>   NAP | Predicted |         95% CI
#> ----------------------------------
#> -1.40 |     13.97 | [10.64, 18.35]
#> -0.80 |     10.30 | [ 8.22, 12.91]
#> -0.20 |      7.60 | [ 6.19,  9.32]
#>  0.40 |      5.60 | [ 4.51,  6.95]
#>  1.00 |      4.13 | [ 3.20,  5.34]
#>  2.20 |      2.25 | [ 1.53,  3.29]
#>
#> [The rest of the output is cut.]
```

```r
ggemmeans(
  fit_glmmTMB, terms = fixed_terms, type = "fixed"
)
#> # Predicted counts of Richness
#> 
#> # Exposure = medium
#> 
#>   NAP | Predicted |         95% CI
#> ----------------------------------
#> -1.40 |     13.97 | [10.64, 18.35]
#> -0.80 |     10.30 | [ 8.22, 12.91]
#> -0.20 |      7.60 | [ 6.19,  9.32]
#>  0.40 |      5.60 | [ 4.51,  6.95]
#>  1.00 |      4.13 | [ 3.20,  5.34]
#>  2.20 |      2.25 | [ 1.53,  3.29]
#> 
#> [The rest of the output is cut.]
```

For comparison I also fitted the Poisson GLMM with [`lme4::glmer`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lme4/versions/1.1-34/topics/glmer). This function doesn't have a `method` option and uses ML. Again, no difference.

```r
fit_glmer <- glmer(
  Richness ~ NAP + Exposure + (1 | Beach),
  family = poisson,
  data = RIKZ
)

ggpredict(
  fit_glmer, terms = fixed_terms, type = "fixed"
)
#> # Predicted counts of Richness
#> 
#> # Exposure = medium
#> 
#>   NAP | Predicted |         95% CI
#> ----------------------------------
#> -1.40 |     13.97 | [10.64, 18.34]
#> -0.80 |     10.30 | [ 8.22, 12.91]
#> -0.20 |      7.60 | [ 6.19,  9.32]
#>  0.40 |      5.60 | [ 4.51,  6.95]
#>  1.00 |      4.13 | [ 3.20,  5.34]
#>  2.20 |      2.25 | [ 1.53,  3.29]
#> 
#> [The rest of the output is cut.]
```

```r
ggemmeans(
  fit_glmer, terms = fixed_terms, type = "fixed"
)
#> # Predicted counts of Richness
#> 
#> # Exposure = medium
#> 
#>   NAP | Predicted |         95% CI
#> ----------------------------------
#> -1.40 |     13.97 | [10.64, 18.34]
#> -0.80 |     10.30 | [ 8.22, 12.91]
#> -0.20 |      7.60 | [ 6.19,  9.32]
#>  0.40 |      5.60 | [ 4.51,  6.95]
#>  1.00 |      4.13 | [ 3.20,  5.34]
#>  2.20 |      2.25 | [ 1.53,  3.29]
#>
#> [The rest of the output is cut.]
```

Comment: Thanks! The question that remains is: why do `ggpredict()` and `ggemmeans()` produce different predictions for mixed-effect models when REML is used? Hopefully someone will be able to shed light on that.